# PHP script cannot see the parent directory

Tags: php

I have a php script on an Apache2 web-server (on Ubuntu). The script creates files. It works well with relative paths specified with `.' but it does not see the parent directory.

```
header('X-Real-Path1: ' . realpath('..')); <-- empty string
header('X-Real-Path2: ' . realpath('.')); <-- returns the actual directory
header('X-Real-Path3: ' . realpath(__DIR__)); <-- returns the actual directory
header('X-Real-Path4: ' . realpath(__DIR__. '/../')); <-- empty string
```

The user which runs the script has full access to the directories. Why doesn't the script see the directories?

The `open_basedir` value is `/var/www/www-root/data:.`

Comment: Have you tried https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: `realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')` works for me. Make sure your PHP process has access to the parent directory.

Comment: `
header('X-Real-Path7: ' . dirname(__DIR__)); <-- works
header('X-Real-Path8: ' . dirname(__DIR__. '/../')); <-- works
header('X-Real-Path9: ' . realpath(__DIR__ . '/..')); <-- does not work
`
file_put_contents( dirname(__DIR__).'/test.qqqqq', 'qqqqq');  <-- does not work as well

Comment: Please tell us more about the environment your script is running. There might be open_basedir restrictions applied. I whould suggest that you check the current value of open_basedir (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Comment: Thank you, @Andreas, the problem was two-fold:
1) there were restrictions in the open_basedir
2) it seems the following lines in the script swallowed the error so I could not see it what it said

Answer (score 1):

The user under which the process runs may not have access to that directory.

From the [manual page](https://php.net/realpath):

> The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise `realpath()` will return `false`.

Your are casting the output to string, and boolean false casts as empty string:

```
var_dump((string)false);
```

```
string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 1):

first check the permissions, and for testing you can set it to **777** just for now.

1. Go to the script parent directory
2. Do this command `sudo chmod 777 -R [dirname]`

### This code should work fine

```
echo(realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));
```

Comment: It already has 777, I've checked it once more, and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the actual directory and cut the last folder, this actually works:

```
$dir = rtrim(__DIR__, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz1234567890');
```

Example:

Actual directory: /home/jVufzc

RUN THE CODE

Output: /home/

If you don't want the final slash do this:

```
$dir = rtrim(__DIR__, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYXZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyxz1234567890');
$dir = rtrim($dir, '/');
```

ABSOLUTELY put them in two different lines, or it will trim all the directory